# Associate/Dissociate related entity on (new) entity

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Is there a way to associate/dissociate one entity to another in CakePHP4.x?
Similar to Laravel's? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships

For instance, if i create a new entity and assign a related entity like this:

```php
    #in a controller
    $entity = $this->Entity->newEmptyEntity();
    $related = $this->Related->get(1);
    $entity->set('related', $related);
```

This will bind $related to `$entity->related` but it wont set `$entity->relation_id = 1`.
I suspect that `$this->Entity->save($entity)` will set $entity->relation_id, but i don't want to save it.

One way to fix it would be:

```php
    $entity->set(['related_id' => $related->id ,'related', $related]);
```

That doesn't look very elegant?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Laravel, but judging from the docs that's not how `attach()` would work, as it seems to be only available for many-to-many relations, where foreign keys do not live in the source side (so there would be no keys to add to the source entity), and it actually inserts data into the database, therefore likely requiring the source to be already persisted?!

Comment: Yes, you're right, attach() is for many-to-many relationships.

BelongsTo works with associate/dissociate
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships
Which also does what i'm looking for.
I've updated the question with associate/dissociate instead of attach/detach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent shorthand method for that in CakePHP.

While `belongsToMany` and `hasMany` associations have [**the `link()` and `unlink()` methods**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/saving-data.html#associate-many-to-many-records) to associate and save entities, there is nothing similar (yet) for `belongsTo` or `hasOne`.

So for now you'd have to manually set the entity on the correct property, and then save the source entity, for example:

```php
$entity = $this->Table->newEmptyEntity(); // or $this->Table->get(1); to update
$entity->set('related', $this->Related->get(1));
$this->Table->save($entity);
```

After saving, the source entity will hold the foreign key(s) of the newly associated record. If you do not actually want to save it (for whatever reason), then you have no choice but to manually set the foreign key(s) on the entity, or to implement your own helper method that is aware of the association configuration, so that it would know which properties to populate.

Just to get you started with something, in a custom [**`\Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/4.2.6/src/ORM/Association/BelongsTo.php) based association class this could look something like this:

```php
public function associate(EntityInterface $source, EntityInterface $target)
{
    $source->set($this->getProperty(), $target);

    $foreignKeys = (array)$this->getForeignKey();
    $bindingKeys = (array)$this->getBindingKey();
    foreach ($foreignKeys as $index => $foreignKey) {
        $source->set($foreignKey, $target->get($bindingKeys[$index]));
    }
}
```

and could then be used like:

```php
$entity = $this->Table->newEmptyEntity();
$this->Table->Related->associate($entity, $this->Related->get(1));
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this and for a possible solution :-)